# How to find who's Next Birthdate given CSV file of Names and Birthdays?

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

We are given a CSV file containing names and birthdays, we have to output who's birthday is next in function.

kept getting a local unbound error, not sure how to fix it, basically trying to read the file, check the dates, find which date is next, then return the name connected with that date

```
birthdates.csv:
Draven Brock,01/21/1952
​Easton Mclean,09/02/1954
​Destiny Pacheco,10/10/1958
​Ariella Wood,12/20/1961
​Keely Sanders,08/03/1985
​Bryan Sloan,04/06/1986
​Shannon Brewer,05/11/1986
​Julianne Farrell,01/29/2000
​Makhi Weeks,03/20/2000
​Lucian Fields,08/02/2010

Function Call:
​nextBirthdate("birthdates.csv", "01/01/2022")

Output:
​Draven Brock
```

```
def nextBirthdate(filename, date):
    f = open(filename, 'r')
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()

    for i in range(len(lines)):
        lines[i] = lines[i].strip()

    # split for the target date
    date = line.split('/')
    month = date[0]
    day = date[1]
    diff = 365
    diffDays = 0
    bName = None
        
    bDays = []
    for line in lines:
        items = line.split(",")
        names = items[0]
        # split the date apart between month, day, and year
        bDay = items[1].split("/")
        bDays.append(bDay)

        for d in bDays:
            if bDay[0] == month:
                if bDay[1] > day:
                    diffDays = int(bDay[0]) - int(day)
                if diffdays < diff:
                    diff = diffDays
                    bName = name
            elif bDay[0] > month:
                diffDays = ((int(bDay[0]) - 1) * 31) + int(day)
                if diffDays < diff:
                    diff = diffDays
                    bName = name

    if bName == None:
        return nextBirthdate(filename, "01/01/2022")

    return bName

if __name__ == "__main__":
    filename = "birthdates.csv"
    date = "12/31/2022"
    print(nextBirthdate(filename, date))
```

Comment: you didn't provide any code you tried so far

Comment: sorry for the confusion

Comment: @nathanb - It took sometime but I got clear idea of your question, please view my solution below

Comment: Because after the last birthday of the year, Ariella Wood's birthday, then during the next year it goes back again to Draven's birthday.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stack overflow.
The way to do this is

1. Read in your CSV data
2. Convert the data to e.g. a [pandas DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html)

   2a. I suggest you convert the dates to e.g. [pd.Timestamp](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html) and not keep them as strings to avoid bad things happening when comparing
3. Sort the DataFrame based on dates, or find the row with the min value, its up to you

How to do each of those things is its own question, that has at least one answer already in stack overflow and other places, so you probably do not need to ask a new one, just search for it.

Answer (score 0):

So here I got this - You just want to know who's next bday it is and want the `name` of the person based on the `CSV` file. Below code should work

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date

def nextBirthdate(file, inp_date):
    d,m,y = [int(x) for x in inp_date.split('/')]
    df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', header=None)
    df[1] = pd.to_datetime(df[1])
    df[1] = df[1].apply(lambda x: x.replace(year=y))
    inp_date = date(y,m,d)
    df['Diff'] = (df[1].dt.date - inp_date).dt.days
    return df.sort_values(by=['Diff'])[0].values[0]

nextBirthdate("birthdates.csv", "01/01/2022")
```

Comment: Welcome buddy :) please upvote and mark it as solution :) it will help back to the community

Comment: it says i need 15

Comment: Oh yeah haha that's okay no proble, :)